# Restart a process if a message is detected on stdout

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, supervisord

Is there a way of monitoring a process (like for example with supervisord), and then restarting the process if the stdout outputs a specific line of text?

In my case the line to check for would be:

```
    Net Exception [in file "src/ErrorHandler.cpp", line 38]
```

If this line is put out on stdout, I would like the process to restart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use "tee" to have stdout also put into a log file, then have a 2nd program monitor the log file, and re-launch the program if it sees the message.

Comment: Does the program that writes that message to standard output terminate after writing it?  If so, does it terminate with an error code?  It'd be a little more natural to monitor the process and its exit status than to monitor what it writes to standard output.

Comment: Unfortunately, the program does not terminate - it sort of spins in a loop and writes the message continuously.

Answer (score 1):

You need to monitor `stdout`, e.g. using grep, so, I don't know, maybe

```
PIDFILE=/tmp/.pid.$$
(
    while true; do
        ./program &
        echo $! > $PIDFILE
        # echo "Program restarted at $( date )" >> /var/log/program.log
    done
) | while read X; do
  echo "$X"
  if (echo "$X" | grep "search" > /dev/null); then
      PID=$( cat $PIDFILE )
      # echo "Found ${X} on $(date), PID ${PID}" >> /var/log/program.log
      kill -TERM $PID
  fi
done
```

The program `program` runs continuously, its output and PID are gathered by the subshell, then if necessary the piped shell will send a TERM signal to the program and have the subshell restart it.

Answer (score -1):

`expect` is the tool for you. Read `man expect`.

`expect` does programmed dialog with interactive programs.